# How to replace case node transaction with newNode transaction using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Below is the input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DST>
  <CDGCreateTree>
    <DST>
      <currentJobName>PQContactComplete</currentJobName>
      <AWD>
        <case>
          <transaction>
            <UIID>001</UIID>
          </transaction>
        </case>
        <case>
          <transaction>
            <UIID>002</UIID>
          </transaction>
        </case>
      </AWD>
    </DST>
  </CDGCreateTree>
  <newNode>
    <transaction relate="Y" id="1"/>   
  </newNode>
</DST>
```

1. In above XML total 2 `case`s which is having individual `transaction`s
2. `newNode` node contains another `transaction` with ID (`id="1"`)

My requirement is like I want to replace first `case` `transaction` with `newNode` `transaction`

Result should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DST>
  <CDGCreateTree>
    <DST>
      <currentJobName>PQContactComplete</currentJobName>
      <AWD>
        <case>
           <transaction relate="Y" id="1"/>   
        </case>
        <case>
          <transaction>
            <UIID>002</UIID>
          </transaction>
        </case>
      </AWD>
    </DST>
  </CDGCreateTree> 
</DST>
```

In the future I may get another `transaction` with `id` under `newNode` node. Below is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DST>
  <CDGCreateTree>
    <DST>
      <currentJobName>PQContactComplete</currentJobName>
      <AWD>
        <case>
           <transaction relate="Y" id="1"/>   
        </case>
        <case>
          <transaction>
            <UIID>002</UIID>
          </transaction>
        </case>
       </AWD>
    </DST>
  </CDGCreateTree> 
  <newNode>
    <transaction relate="Y" id="2"/>   
  </newNode>
</DST>
```

This time I should replace second `case` `transaction` with `newNode` `transaction` (because first `case` `transaction` is already having `id` value).
I want to continue the process in that way.

I have tried the XSLT below but it didn't help. Please suggest a better approach or correct me if I am wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version = "1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>         
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="targetNode" select="//newNode/transaction"/>

    <xsl:template match="(//transaction[ancestor::*[name() = "CDGCreateTree"]][not(@id)])[1]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$targetNode"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//newNode">
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Explanation of above XSL:

`(//transaction[ancestor::*[name() = "CDGCreateTree"]][not(@id)])[1]` this statement is defines about `case` `transaction` which is not having `id` and first `transaction`
replace with `(//newNode/transaction)` New `transaction`.

In the future if I get any `newNode` `transaction` it should be replaced accordingly to above XSL. I thought it will work as per the statement but something is missing.

Comment: "*I want to replace NewNode transaction with first case transaction*" Why would you want to do such a thing? The first case transaction is already there - what's the point of duplicating it? And why would you want to lose the information regarding the NewNode transaction?

Comment: 1)NewNode transaction which contains response based on execution of case transaction data

Comment: after that no more useful for us about case transaction data, that is the reason why we are deleting that data replacing with newNode transaction data. this is migration project we need to follow what had done previously.

Comment: This would make sense if you were replacing the old transaction with the new one, not the other way around. Also, shouldn't the replacement be based on matching the new transaction's id with some property of the old transaction?

Comment: yes you are right,Replace case transaction with New node transaction, My way of asking the question is wrong

Comment: "shouldn't the replacement be based on matching the new transaction's id with some property of the old transaction?" there is no matching condition from my side to replace the content

Comment: Michael,I have updated my question once agin, I think have given good explanation of about my problem, I hope you will understand me now, Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure I understand this completely, but try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="new-transaction" match="newNode/transaction" use="count(preceding-sibling::transaction)" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="case/transaction[key('new-transaction', count(preceding::transaction))]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('new-transaction', count(preceding::transaction))"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="newNode"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will replace old transactions with new ones, progressing in document order until there are no more new transactions (in which case the remaining old transactions are kept), or until there are no more old transactions (in which case the remaining new transactions are discarded), which ever comes first.

Applied to a **mininized input example**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DST>
  <CDGCreateTree>
    <DST>
      <currentJobName>PQContactComplete</currentJobName>
      <AWD>
        <case>
           <transaction>
            <UIID>001</UIID>
          </transaction>
        </case>
        <case>
          <transaction>
            <UIID>002</UIID>
          </transaction>
        </case>
        <case>
          <transaction>
            <UIID>003</UIID>
          </transaction>
        </case>
      </AWD>
    </DST>
  </CDGCreateTree>
  <newNode>
    <transaction relate="Y" id="1"/>
    <transaction relate="Y" id="2"/>
  </newNode>
</DST>
```

the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DST>
   <CDGCreateTree>
      <DST>
         <currentJobName>PQContactComplete</currentJobName>
         <AWD>
            <case>
               <transaction relate="Y" id="1"/>
            </case>
            <case>
               <transaction relate="Y" id="2"/>
            </case>
            <case>
               <transaction>
                  <UIID>003</UIID>
               </transaction>
            </case>
         </AWD>
      </DST>
   </CDGCreateTree>
</DST>
```

Comment: But my input xml generated like newNode  contains only one transaction each time, so we need to replace each case transaction with newNode transaction.

Comment: I have requested another post based an my requirement is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932290/replacing-nodes-in-xml-using-xslt

Comment: @Hari I am afraid you're (again) not being clear. Please take my minimized input example, edit it to reflect your input structure and add this to your question.

Comment: I have removed my question which is posted previously, please let me know if I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Hari Your question in its current form makes no sense. There is no `<transaction relate="Y" id="2"/>` in the input - so it cannot appear in the output either. -- And please DELETE [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932290/replacing-nodes-in-xml-using-xslt).

Comment: during the process of  second loop some xsl's are there to generaten newNode transaction with the help of second case transaction , i cant display you total xsl's which i have in middle that is the reason why i am showing in the skeletion way

Comment: @Hari Sorry, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Hi Michael,i got solution for above problem below is the post i have given, thanks your support.

Answer (score 0):

```
1)In first loop suppose count value contains 1, case transaction replaced with new transaction which contains.
2)In second loop the count value contains 2, so the second case transaction replaced with newNode transaction which contains.
3)Always newNode transaction contains new transaction which is generated dynamically.

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version = "1.0">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>         
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="counter" select="//sample/count"/>

<xsl:variable name="targetNode" select="//newNode/transaction"/>

<xsl:template match="case[$counter]/transaction">
   <xsl:copy-of select="$targetNode"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//sample/count">
<count>
   <xsl:value-of select="$counter + 1"/>
 </count>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The input XML does not contain `sample` nor `count` - so this cannot be the answer to the question you have asked.

Comment: before this xsl i have so many xsl's are there to process in loop, that is the reason why i have taken count and sample nodes in another xsl before of this xsl. And initialized count variable with "1".